# duplicate file/folder finder application for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, deduplication

I got old archives of my old computers,
 Now I decided to merge all these folders and organize them, I got many backups so I need app that will find duplicate files and delete / move them, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools which accomplish what you want. You can use the [Advance System Care](http://www.iobit.com/advancedsystemcareper.html). I use it and its much pretty cool tool.  It has many feature and of course what are you looking for.
You can also use [Duplicate File Finder](http://www.duplicate-finder-download.com/). All features are listed there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personaly use TreeSize Free is a free disk space manager for Windows. The software shows you the sizes of folders including all subfolders

> [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/index.shtml)
>    tells you where precious disk space has gone and has a featured to find Duplicate File with hash. There's a free version or you can test the PRO product 30 days for free as fully-functional trial version.

[image]